# How can I calculate this using integer data types only?

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to program the following in C, using MPLABX IDE and XC8 compiler, for a PIC12 microcontroller. I've programmed neither microcontrollers nor C before, so there are some new things I need to consider. One being that calculations using float types are inefficient on these microcontrollers and should therefore be avoided. Trying to follow that philosophy, I would like to know the best practice for doing a calculation like this:

> a = b / c * d

Where:

> 0 =< a =< d,
>
> 0 =< b =< c,
>
> 0 =< c,
>
> 0 =< d

a, b and c are unsigned 16 bit integers. d can be chosen freely.

I am looking for a good compromise between good legible source code, and efficient compiled code.

I have considered restructuring the equation, but avoiding one problem introduces another:

> a = b / c * d

--> b/c will always be 0. Remainder is lost.

> a = b * d / c

--> b*d may produce overflow.

Comment: Do the multiplication before the division, using a larger type if there will be overflow. `a = (int)((long long)b * d / c);` If you want to round the result you can add (or subtract if negative product) half the divisor `c >> 1` before dividing.

Comment: Could you please specify what result you want. If `a` is an integer, it quite possibly can't hold the result of the division exactly. Do you want to truncate? round? Do you want the remainder, or is it ok to discard it?

Comment: @Weather Vane. Thanks so much, that's the solution I was hoping for, even on a single line of code! Why not make it the answer? I'll accept. Could you tell me also, if I can take it for granted that the compiler will do the math in the same order as I have entered it?

Comment: Re "*can take it for granted that the compiler will do the math in the same order as I have entered it*", In general, most definitely not. But operator associativity dictates that the multiplication happens before the division because it's on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the multiplication before the division, using a larger type if there will be overflow.

```
a = (int)((long long)b * d / c);
```

If you are doubtful about the sequence of operations you can parenthesise it

```
a = (int)(((long long)b * d) / c);
```

although it is unnecessary, because although `*` and `/` have the same precendence they are parsed from left to right.

If you want to round the result you can add (or subtract if negative product) half the divisor before dividing.

```
a = (int)(((long long)b * d + (c >> 1)) / c);
```

Comment: With your `0 =< c` watch out for division by `0`.

Comment: Minor: If the goal is "half the divisor", why `(c >> 1)` instead of `c/2`?  BTW the add/subtract idea is dependent not only sign of product, but sign of product and sign of `c`.

Comment: @chux agreed it's best left to the compiler, but my (not recent) experience of PIC compilers was not great. Also, all values are non-negative in the question.